# Azure SQL Database - Does Increasing Data Max Size via Azure Portal Interrupt Service

Tags: azure-sql-database

I'd like to increase the database Max Size while the application utilizing the database is running.

Will scaling it up have any noticeable impact? This is a small scale application; a minute of down time would be OK. More than that and I'd have to push off the upgrade to outside of business hours. Thank you.

Comment: [Scale single database resources in Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-single-database-scale)

Comment: I was hoping for a better answer than 'Typically less than 5 minutes'. Guess I'll take it. Thanks for the prompt response!

Comment: what's your database price tier, DTU-base or Vcore-base?

Comment: Be aware that table is about the total time to change a reservation size.  It does not mean that you are down during that whole time window - usually it just needs to disconnect you at the end of seeding (which happens in the background) and you reconnect.  That failover process is usually almost immediate (seconds).  Rarely it can take longer.

Comment: DB Config is Standard tier 0 (S0), DTU based.  I kept the DTUs at 10, bumped the Data max size from 2GB to 5GB. It took about 20 seconds from the time I started the process until the portal notified me the process was complete.

Comment: @IdusOrtus As you said, a minute of down time would be OK. Scale the database took 20 seconds,   I think this latency(20s) is  within your acceptable time range.

Comment: Hi @IdusOrtus,If my answer is helpful for you, can you please vote it or accept(mark) it as answer? This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, a minute of down time would be OK. Scaling the database took you 20 seconds,   I think this latency is within your acceptable time range.

The document [Scale single database resources in Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-single-database-scale) only can give you the reference max time : "Typically, less than 5 minute".

The latency usually depended on the current Azure SQL database price tier and the target server price tier which you want scale up to.

We can not calculate the specific latency time for you. It's all happening in Azure background.

Hope this helps.